# I can't read my POST HTTP request's body with PHP !

Tags: php, post

I've never used PHP but right now, I need to write a PHP file that displays in a log file the content of the body of a POST HTTP request.

I've read that you can access variables of the body via the _POST array.
Unfortunately, it seems to be empty, although I'm pretty sure there is stuff in my HTTP request's body !

What should I use to be 100% sure of the content of my HTTP body ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
$post_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

> `php://input` allows you to read raw POST data. It is a less memory intensive alternative to `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` and does not need any special php.ini directives. `php://input` is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

<sup>(Source: http://php.net/wrappers.php)</sup>

Comment: One thing to note: i was posting to my website such as www.example.com/test and i could not get php://input to work.  It turns out i had to post to www.example.com/test/index.php

Comment: I just needed that again today and I had the opportunity to use this trick. Very efficient. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The global variable is `$_POST`, not `_POST`. Also it might be that you are sending the data via `GET` method, in which case you need to use the `$_GET` global variable.

If you want to check for either `POST` or `GET` method, you can use the global variable `$_REQUEST`. Sample code bellow:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="postdata.php">
<input type="text" name="mydata" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

file **postdata.php**:

```
<?php

$result = $_POST['mydata'];
echo $result;
```

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but I've convinced my client to use a GET method. But I'll keep all the answers here in mind for any future need ! Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you misspelled it. The array's correct name `$_POST`.

Try this

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
```

and see what happens.