# Retrofit does not deliver Java Object as POST parameters on PHP backend from Android

Tags: java, php, android, retrofit, retrofit2

Using Retrofit I want to POST values of Java Object as parameters to the PHP script on backend side. But using the code below i am not able to receive any parameters inside `$_POST` variable.

Here is how I am doing this right now.

**1) This is how I build and get the Retrofit Instance**

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.example.com";

    public static Retrofit getInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**2) The Model of the parameters being sent**

```
public class LoginModel {

    @SerializedName("email")
    private String email;

    @SerializedName("password")
    private String password;

    public LoginModel(String email, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public String getPassword() { return password; }
}
```

**3) The API Interface**

```
public interface RequestAPI {

    @POST("/login")
    Call<ResponseBody> getResponse(@Body LoginModel loginModel) ;
}
```

**4) And this is how I fire the request and catch the response**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel("user@example.com", "123");

    RequestAPI service = RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(RequestAPI.class);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.getResponse(loginModel);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            try {
                Log.e("=====", response.body().string());
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("=====", "error", t);
        }
    });
}
```

**5) PHP script in backend**

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Now every time i dump the $_POST variable. It just gives an **empty array**.

Am I missing on any thing.

Why am i not receiving the **email** and **password** as the child of $_POST?

Comment: did you check response.isSuccessful() ??

Comment: Have you tried with **`@FormUrlEncoded`** data? looks like raw request body can't be accessed via `echo json_encode($_POST);`

Comment: @JeelVankhede I tried using `@FormUrlEncoded` , That works,  **BUT** that does not allow the Java Object to pass as @Body.

Comment: @Radesh yes it gives true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use like this for **API method**:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/login")
Call<ResponseBody> getResponse(@Field("email") String email, @Field("password") String password) ;
```

& call like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

LoginModel loginModel = new LoginModel("user@example.com", "123");

RequestAPI service = RetrofitClient.getInstance().create(RequestAPI.class);

Call<ResponseBody> call = service.getResponse(loginModel.getEmail(), loginModel.getPassword());

call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
        try {
            Log.e("=====", response.body().string());
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
        Log.e("=====", "error", t);
    }
});
}
```

---

**Edit:**

If you still want to pass custom object as raw body of API call then there will be change for **PHP** side code :

Instead of using

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

consider using

```
$post_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

as this alternate method provides whole raw request body as variable directly rather than providing it as **JSON object** to be encode.

Comment: I already done that. But that does not solve my problem as I want to pass Java Object as the parameter. In my question there is just a sample example. I would use it in more complex scenarios.

Comment: Then you'll need to change your receiver code of **PHP** side because, clearly you can't directly receive your custom raw body in `json_encoded` format. check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3362257/10271334

Comment: Amazing :) Many Thanks for the solution. Also please update your answer with the information that you provided so that I can accept the answer. And so that it can be more helpful to any other developer having same question.

Comment: @kanudo please consider editing as your convenience, I've just provided glimpse as edit.