# Cannot read body of post request with php

Tags: php, post

I'm trying to use an online service that requires to read the body of post requests at a callback url (webhook).

However I'm not familiar with http requests and unable to read the received data.

I'm using [file_get_contents('php://input')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362145/i-cant-read-my-post-http-requests-body-with-php) to retrieve the body and store the result in a text file :

```
file_put_contents("log/test.txt", file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

I received data look like this in notepad++ (weird characters) :
[image]

Any idea on what's happening here ?

EDIT : Full code

```
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>

<body>

    <?php

        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/db_functions.php';

        file_put_contents("log/test.txt", file_get_contents('php://input'));

    ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a full code example? I guess the received data is encoded / binary stream

Comment: And commonly requires looking at the HTTP request headers (Content-Encoding).

Comment: are you sure that curl installs in your system??

Comment: @Isitar : I added the code above

Comment: @mario : could you be more specific ?

Comment: @IstiyakAmin : yes Curl is installed but how is it relevant here ?

Comment: $test_get = file_get_contents("log/test.txt");
var_dump($test_get);

first check what the return value of $test_get

Comment: @istiyakamin : I get "string(113524) "��+f]�i[�J�....." followed by a lot of these characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are posting binary data.
You are posting an image/wavfile/document.
You can convert it back to what it was and save it to a directory.

```
$target_dir = "files/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]); // file = your input name
$target_file = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $target_file);
$uploadOk = 1;
$FileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 5000000) {
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "Your file ". preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"])). " is uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, an error occured";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot : When you mentionned "document" I realized data could have been compressed. It really helped.

Comment: sadly not. I dont have enough points. I would have done it of course... sorry

Comment: @Bruno mark my answer as best, now the question stays open

Answer (score 0):

It appears that **data were gzipped**...

So the simple solution is to use **GZDECODE** :

```
file_put_contents("log/test.txt", gzdecode(file_get_contents('php://input')));
```